# Не работает dbase в php 5.3 и 5.4

Tags: php, dll

Скачал dll для 5.3, она скомпилина с vc6, а мне надо с vc9 и желательно чтобы под 5.4 тоже работала.
Нужно чтобы работало под linux'ом на боевом сервере, для win уже нашел.

Comment: Так, нашел для 5.3 vc9, теперь нужно для 5.4

Comment: дадада, работает с 5.4, спасибо.

Ни разу php сам не компилировал, надо будет попробовать...

Comment: Выяснилось что вариант с dll будет работать у меня на винде и не будет работать на сервере под линукс ))
Что делать?

Comment: Ну вроде на сервере все скомпилили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/dbase.installation.php

Установка

Для того, чтобы подключить dbase библиотеку и использовать ее функции, скомпилируйте PHP с опцией --enable-dbase .

т.е. у вас она либо уже есть либо вам надо поискать другую сборку php, или собрать самому.

ну и ещё гугль [как бы намекает](http://hrazdil.info/blog/414-php-dbase-extension-for-php-5-4-windows-nts-ts-vc9)